# USA H-1B visa - Application is not updated for "No-show" update for dependents

Tags: usa, application-status

I am an Indian citizen and have received an H-1B visa.

I had a drop-off appointment at the US visa office Mumbai VAC on 28 August 2023. Appointment was for H4-Drop off for myself and for my dependents.

My dependents' visas were not processed as they don't have earlier visas for drop-off eligibility. `As per the consulate officer, we have to reschedule the appointment for biometric and interview once the No-Show will be done on their appointment.

I have already registered the case for this on 30 August 2023 to update No show for my dependents' appointment. Since then, I am trying every day to connect with the US visa customer care and asking them to get an update on the No Show. All the time they said that the standard response time is 24 to 48 hours. However, even after 30 days, **the status is not being updated for No-Show**. Nobody is even acknowledging what the issue is with the process of No Show.

Also, the cases I created as a request/complaint are getting marked as closed/resolved.

My office is unable to provide any guidance on this either.

Can someone please tell me what else I can do here?

Comment: Pratik - Did you get a solution to this? I am stuck due to the same issue as well.